How can I run a loop forever until a termination condition or for a fixed number of iterations?
I have a program that runs an operation either a fixed number of times, or "forever" until some condition is reached. The implementation was fine, but I was having trouble getting a code structure I was happy with.
My initial logic boiled down to:
max_iterations = 5 # Either an integer or None (the number actually comes from user input)
stop_flag = False

i = 0
while not stop_flag:
    do_some_operation(i)
    i += 1
    stop_flag = (i == max_iterations) or test_some_stop_condition()

But I wasn't very happy with this, I don't like that there's both an i variable and a stop flag.
The stop flag can be eliminated by moving the logic to the while:
i = 0
while not ((i == max_iterations) or test_some_stop_condition()):
    do_some_operation(i)
    i += 1

but this seems even less readable to me. That conditional is not particularly understandable now it's moved to the while.
So, I used itertools.count to do the iteration:
import itertools
max_iterations = 5 # Either an integer or None (the number actually comes from user input)
for i in itertools.count():
    do_some_operation(i)
    if (i == max_iterations) or test_some_stop_condition():
        break

I'm not very happy with this either, but I think it's reasonably clean and readable. Ideally I think the termination condition should be entirely in the for or while, leaving the body of the loop entirely for the actual work, but I can't think of a way to do it cleanly.
Is there a better solution?
Some notes:

the i variable is required, since do_some_operation makes use of it.
test_some_stop_condition() can still return True regardless of whether i is None or an int. This is fine.

(This question might be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, I'm honestly not sure...)

while i < max_iterations and not test_some_stop_condition():.  It's really a matter of opinion and not suitable for SO.

while i < max_iterations will raise an exception when max_iterations == None. I agree it's opinion-based if I've covered basically most of the good options, but I thought there there might be some solution that was clearly the right way to do it.

while (max_iterations is None or i < max_iterations) and ...

You could also use math.inf instead of None to indicate that there's no limit on the number of iterations.

max_iterations could be handled with
for i in islice(count(), max_iterations):

or
for i in count() if max_iterations is None else range(max_iterations):

or if int values are always positive:
for i in range(max_iterations) if max_iterations else count():


Your top suggestion is very good, but I think I actually prefer the bottom one, it's understandable without needing to go lookup what islice does. Thanks!

Instead of using a while loop or itertools with a for loop, why don't you try a normal for loop? Since you already know how many iterations you want to do, why not use range with a for loop?
for i in range(max_iterations + 1):
    do_some_operation(i)
    
    if test_some_stop_condition():
        break

range() returns a sequence of numbers, which in your case would represent the number of iterations every loop. If only one value is given, then the sequence will automatically begin at 0 and stop before the value given (thus why we put max_iterations + 1). Simply put, we're just going through a list of consecutive/incrementing numbers.
Like it should, when the for loop reaches the last number in the sequence, the for loop will automatically end, so you wouldn't need if i == max_iterations.
Additionally, even if you do end up having multiple termination conditions, I recommend that you separate them into separate conditions instead of using or or alternatively you can create a function that checks for all of them. This way you can get into a habit of writing clean and readable code and reduces the amount of bugs you might run into and the amount of time to fix bugs (woohoo!).

max_iterations can be None, implying that it should loop forever until the other stop condition is reached.

@jfowkes I see that now, sorry about that. I think the best way to deal with that would be with itertools.count then. You could also put all the code into a function instead and do a conditional to check whether to run for or while, but that probably wouldn't be very readable. However, for the termination conditionals, I'd still recommend creating a separate function with all of the possible termination conditions.

So there are two relevant cases:

max_count is not set: the loop should stop on test_some_stop_condition() == true; and
max_count is int (and > 0): the loop should stop on test_some_stop_condition() == true or i == max_count

The straightforward way to move these conditions to the loop statement is to inline them:
i = 0
while not (test_some_stop_condition() or i == max_count):
    do_some_operation(i)
    i+=1

This satisfies the first case: i == max_count will be false if max_count is None, and the second case: the condition will evaluate to true on first arrival, and the loop will stop.

You could further simplify the condition by using a more semanticaly correct value for the case that there's no upper bound - like floating point infinity float('inf') or math.inf
max_iterations = float('inf')
i = 0
while i < max_iterations and not test_some_stop_condition():
    do_some_operation(i)
    i+=1


Alternatively a more "clean" (albeit very overkill) solution you could try:
Define your own generator that takes a condition:
def conditionalRange(condition = lambda:False,max_iterations = float('inf')):
    max_iterations = max_iterations or float('inf')
    if condition(): return
    i = 0
    while i < int(max_iterations):
        yield i
        i += 1

So your loop would look like:
for i in conditionalRange(test_some_stop_condition,max_iterations):
    do_some_operation(i)

(Note that you should pass the function object to conditionalRange without calling it)

Lastly do_some_operation() depends on the state of that loop, particularly the iteration count, so maybe the loop should be contained within it.
